# Google Apps Script - DriveApp.getFoldersByName - Won't get files as expected - Trying to get FileID from Folder Name

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get an ID from a Folder name in a Google Apps script. The Folder name is unique.

Right now I have:

```
var folderID = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(fileName).next().getId()
```

I've also tried:

```
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(fileName)
while (folders.hasNext()) {
var folder = folders.next()
var fileID = folder.getId()
}
```

Both instances tell me "Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end."

I know this Folder exists, it is in my drive. I've tried copying the name of the file verbatim, placing it in quotes, and putting it into the getFoldersByName function and have had no success.

If it helps, the folder is down a bit on the file structure. DriveFile1>DriveFile2>DriveFile3>FileToBeFound

Any ideas?

Even if I search for a small section of the file name, then try to iterate through it doesn't find anything.

The goal here is to place form uploads into the correct folder based on the user that uploads it. Usernames are unique and they can't have the ability to edit the file after they upload. Everything else works great, I just can't pull the file ID from the Folder Name

Comment: Are they always going to be in DriveFile3?

Comment: Drivefile3 is more like it will always be three files down a chain. Ie UnchangingRootFolder>year>name>uniquefileID + descriptor

Answer (score 3):

Just to be sure try this:

```
function getFolderId(foldername) {
  var foldername=foldername||'Folder Name';
  var folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
  var n=0;
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder=folders.next();
    n++;
  }
  if(n==1) {
    Logger.log(folder.getId());
    return folder.getId();
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("More that one folder with the name " + foldername);
  }
}
```

Comment: I added a check of n>1 to make sure it was actually finding more than one, and it is still finding nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix using:

`var folderName = <myuniquefoldername>`

`folderName = "Title Contains '"+folderName + "'"`

`var folderID = DriveApp.searchFolders(folderName).next().getId()`

Which will store the folderID in there. I wasn't able to get getFoldersByName to work at all. No matter what I put in there it would find nothing.