# Automate move file from one folder to other specific folder by name on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made a script using AppScript to move data from Google Form response to a Google Docs Template and the Google Docs result will be uploaded automatically to one folder with the script:

```
var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("");
var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");
```

It went well!

But now I want them to be sorted to another folder by the exact part of the file name as the keyword, and the name of the folders will be the exact part of the file name that were used as the keyword.

For example, the file name is "Test Result Harry - Gryffindor", I want all files with "Gryffindor" in it to be moved to a new folder named "Gryffindor" automatically.

I am very new to this scripting world but am willing to learn this for my project.

I've tried searching for similar case from the internet but haven't found the exact case and script that I need in this condition.

Comment: let lastname = file.getName().slice(file.getName().indexOf('-') + 1)

Comment: @Cooper I may be wrong but... I think you need `+2`. `indexOf` will return the position of the dash; then you have to add two (2) to account for the dash itself plus the space following.

Comment: May I clarify... 1) `I want them to be sorted to another folder` - do you mean copied to another folder , or moved to another folder, or maybe something else? 2) `by the exact part of the file name as the keyword` Is the keyword is the last word of the file name? (the bit after the "dash")? Would you please provide a worked example of how you want files to be "sorted".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move File to a Different Folder in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384864/move-file-to-a-different-folder-in-google-drive)

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz! I want them moved to another folder, and Yes, the keyword is the last word of the file name after the "dash" symbol, hope you could help me on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have files in a given folder.

You want to move those files to sub-folders that are named for a keyword contained in the file name.

The keyword for any file name is the last word of the file name (excluding the extension) following " - " (space,dash,space).

For example, if the file name = "Test Result Harry - Gryffindor" then the keyword = "Gryffindor"

---

- Load the script into a project editor. I used a project bound to a Spreadsheet.
- Update the Folder ID of the folder where the files are currently located.
- run `moveFiles`

---

**UPDATE - improve detection of existing folder**

```
function moveFiles(){
  var parentFolderID = "<<Insert Parent Folder ID>>"
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderID)
  var files = folder.getFiles()

  // loop through the files
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: FILE NAME = "+fileName)
    // get the file name WITHOUT extension
    var filenameNoExt=fileName.slice(0,fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
    // get the keyword following the dash in the file name
    var keyword = filenameNoExt.slice(filenameNoExt.indexOf('-') + 2)
    
    // test if a "keyword" folder exists
    var getFolders = folder.getFoldersByName(keyword)

    // test how many folders exist
    // set counter to zero
    var n=0;
    while(getFolders.hasNext()) {
      var getFldr=getFolders.next()
      n++;
    }
    // if n > 1 then stop and give user alert
    // if n == 0 then create folder
    // if n == 1 then folder already exists
    if (n>1){
      // multiple folders of that name
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: n = "+n+", keyword = "+keyword+",multiple folders")
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("More that one folder with the name " + keyword)
      break
    }else if(n==0) {
      // folder doesn't exist, so create the folder 
      var newFolder = folder.createFolder(keyword)
      var newFolderID = newFolder.getId()
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: n = "+n+", created folder = "+newFolder+", Folder ID="+newFolderID)
    }else if(n==1) {
      // folder exists, so just get the folder ID
      var newFolderID = getFldr.getId()
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: n= "+n+", keyword = "+keyword+", folder exists. Folder ID = "+newFolderID)
    }

    // move the file
    file.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderID))
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: moved "+fileName+" to "+keyword)
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE DATA (BEFORE-FILE LIST)**

[image: files]

---

**SAMPLE DATA (AFTER - FOLDER LIST)**

[image: folders]

---

**SAMPLE DATA (AFTER - Gryffindor Folder)**

### [image: Gryffindor]

h/t @Cooper for snipett to detection of existing folder

- StackOverflow [DriveApp.getFoldersByName - Won't get files as expected - Trying to get FileID from Folder Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532638/1330560)

Comment: from the script above do I just need to change the Folder ID for the Parent Folder ID? Or do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Just the parent Folder FolderID.

Comment: Thank you it worked! But I was wondering as the result why the folder name is missing one last letter. For example: "Grffindor" should be the folder name but it shows "Gryffindo" instead

Comment: What is the file name?

Comment: Call Report Regular Harry - Gryffindor

Comment: @GandyDesArdy I don't know why your file didn't work. I've done extensive testing and have a 100% success rate. OTOH, please note that I have updated the script to improve the detection of an existing folder but this shouldn't affect the problem you described.

Comment: thank you so much for trying, it helps me a lot. I couldn't figure the problem myself until now but it's okay. I actually have another case about scripting I posted few hours ago, is there any chance you can help me with that? ^^